# Adding a HyperLink to apex:messages on VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, error-messages

Is there any way embed a link in an apex:Messages error message?
Below is the apex:Mesages compnent on my VF page. I cannot use apex:PageMessages because it does not support the style resources that I am using.

```
<apex:Messages styleclass="alert alert-error errorStyling" />
```

The most common solution I am seeing is to set the escape attribute to "false" under PageMessages, but this attribute is not supported in apex:Messages, only PageMessages.

Is there any way to add  a link to Page:Messages like the link below?

```
String err = 'Testing For Message Link: <a href="http://www.google.com">Google or Something</a>.';
        ApexPages.addMessage(New ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error, err));

          PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();  
              return pageRef;
```

Best,
CP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `escape="false"` and you need to use `apex:pageMessages` for `escape`

```
String err = 'Testing For Message Link: <a href="http://www.google.com">Google or Something</a>.';
```

### **In Page**

```
<apex:pageMessages styleclass="alert alert-error errorStyling" escape="false"/>
```

---

### Updates

If you can't use `apex:pageMessages` then use `apex:outputText` with `escapse='false'`

You can display this `outputText` when this string having value

```
<apex:outputText styleclass="alert alert-error errorStyling" escape="false" 
     value="{!errorString}" rendered = "{!(errorString != '')}" />
```

---

In Controller

```
public string str {get; private set;}

 str = 'Testing For Message Link: <a href="http://www.google.com">Google or Something</a>.';
```

IN VF page

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!str}"></apex:outputText>
```

---

**NOTE:-** As [**@Mohith Shrivastava**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/645/mohith-shrivastava) **said If you are building an appexchange product ,this wont pass security review .escape=false is not an option from security review perspective**

Comment: the escape attribute is only supported in pageMessages. I cannot use pageMessages, I have to use Messages because of the style resources used.

Comment: @ChrisP You can use apex:outputText and assign this string and use escape="false" for `apex:outputText` and You can add css to that `apex:outputText`

Comment: so it appears that the issue with that is the following: I get the messae "the value of attribute "value" in apex:outputText must not contain the '<' character.   I am using te same kind of link as in my question. Maybe certain characters need to be escaped?

Comment: @ChrisP `<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!str}"></apex:outputText>` this is working for me

Comment: @ChrisP store your HTML in string and then use in VF page..

Comment: Got it. This was helpful. For me, this link is meant to be in a conditional error message, so I set up a local Boolean variable and set the component to render when it is true. Many Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisP instead creating a Boolean variable you can use `rendered = "{!(errorString != '')}"` string empty or not and bsed on that display message

Comment: @Ratan Heads up !!! If you are building an appexchange product ,this wont pass security review .escape=false is not an option from security review perspective

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Thanks for info.. I was not aware of that..